# Use integer with cells property

Tags: excel, vba, increment

Trying to use an integer as part of a cell reference (to set the row value). The script executes in full but always calls the same cell instead of looping through column A. What am I missing?

```
Sub GetURL()

 Dim i As Integer
 i = 1

 Dim url As String
 url = Sheets("urls").Cells(i, 1)

 Do While i < 5

 ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=url, NewWindow:=True

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

 i = i + 1

 Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Move `url = Sheets("urls").Cells(i, 1)` inside the loop.

Comment: Btw - normally you use a `For` loop to loop through rows, not a `Do While` loop.

Comment: Spot on! New to VBA hence why syntax is weak.

Comment: Also, in general, you should use the `Long` data type instead of `Integer`. In your code, it won't make a difference. But `Integer` is limited to `32,767` and there are more rows than that.  Also, I have read that VBA converts `Integer` to `Long` internally anyway (except you'll get an Overflow error if the value exceeds the Integer limit).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good to know, kind of detail that might not be obvious at first. Thank you.